# Como solucionó este error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in"

Tags: php

Hola alguien podria orientarme con respecto a estos errores en mi consulta:

"Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in"
"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in"

Aqui la consulta:

```
    <?php

require_once'inc/connection.php';
                           
                        
        $mySql =mysqli_query( "SELECT libros.*,  kategori.nm_kategori FROM libros 
                    LEFT JOIN kategori ON libros.kd_kategori=kategori.kd_kategori 
                    ORDER BY libros.kd_libro ASC LIMIT $mulan, $baris");
    
    $mySql = mysqli_query($konexdb, $mySql) or die ("Error en la consulta".mysqli_error($konexdb)); 
    
        $nomor = 0;
        while ($librosData = mysqli_fetch_array($mySql)) {
            
            $KodeLibro = $libroData['kd_libro'];
            $KodeKategori = $libroData['kd_kategori'];
            
            
            if ($libroData['file_start']=="") {
                $fileStart = "noimage.jpg";
            }
            else {
                $filefileStart  = $libroData['file_start'];
            }
        ?>
```

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Te falta pasarle la conexión, lee aquí https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: gracias por comentar aun me sigue dando los mismo errores que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Saludos. Leo aplicaste algunos de los comentarios y respuesta que recibiste; te sugiero pruebes tu código bien y actualices colocando (en lo posible) el error actual; en el código que esta ahora tienes 2 veces ` $mySql =` y en el segundo esta `$mySql = mysqli_query($konexdb, $mySql)` lo cual es incorrecto por que debe ser el 2do parámetro el SQL a ejecutar

Answer (score 0):

depues de la apertura de tu etiqueta:

```
<?php
```

colocas lo siguiente:

```
require_once'conexion.php';
```

> este s tu código para llamar a la conexión hacia tu base de datos.

Ahora bien, tu archivo conexión.php lo creas de esta manera:

```
<?php 

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'tu-usuario_php_my_admin', '', 'el_nombre_de_tu_baseDeDatos');

    if($db->connect_errno) {
        printf("Ha ocurrido un Error al conectar con la base de datos",$mysql->connect_errno);
    }

?>
```

Te sugieron tambien revisar los espacio es tú codigo, en el código que nos dejastes...

Comment: Hola CristianB amigo mio aun me sigue dando el mismo error de todos modos gracias